# Javascript change action and then submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Today I saw something really strange. I have an ordinary HTML form, which I wanted to check with JS. The initial form action was ="javascript:submit();" and my submit() function was:

```
function submit() {
    .... code ...
    form.getAttributeNode("action").value = "/SomeController"; // because I have an hidden element named "action"
    form.submit();
}
```

first time when the function is called it just change the action attribute, but it do not submit form at all but if I call it twice, then the form is submitted?

By changing the logic of checking with JS I managed to do it, but why the above method didn't work ? What did I miss ?

Comment: Trying to submit a form that is already in process of being submitted seems very quirky. No doubt there are plenty of opportunities to shoot yourself in a foot. As a rule of a thumb, just wrap your `form.submit()` in a  `setTimeout(..., 0)` and save yourself a headache.

Comment: Bind to the onsubmit event instead of calling a function in the action